# Telegraph ошибка CONTENT_FORMAT_INVALID при отправке запроса на создание страницы (createPage)

Tags: telegram-bot, api, requests

NodeArray (content) делал по примеру из [документации](https://telegra.ph/api#:%7E:text=Sample%20request%0Ahttps%3A//api.telegra.ph/createPage%3Faccess_token%3Dd3b25feccb89e508a9114afb82aa421fe2a9712b963b387cc5ad71e58722%26title%3DSample%2BPage%26author_name%3DAnonymous%26content%3D%5B%7B%22tag%22%3A%22p%22%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%22Hello%2C%2Bworld!%22%5D%7D%5D%26return_content%3Dtrue) и [этому](https://habr.com/ru/post/587430/#:%7E:text=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%22tag%22%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0A%20%20%22children%22%3A%20%5B%22Hello%20world%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D).

```
def create_page(self, title: str, data_page: json) -> str:
        data={
            'access_token': self.token,
            'title': title,
            'author_name': self.author_name,
            'content': [
                            {
                            "tag": "b",
                            "children": ["Hello world"]
                            }
                       ],
            'return_content':'false'
        }
        
        page=requests.get("https://api.telegra.ph/createPage?", params=data)
        print(page.json())
        #return page.json()
```

Вывод `{'ok': False, 'error': 'CONTENT_FORMAT_INVALID'}`

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Отправил вместо листа строку '[{"tag":"p","children":["Hello, world!"]}]', все заработало...